Can't burn ERC20 tokens in Solidity
I am newbie who is starting to learn Solidity.  I am working on a project that utilizes ERC20, and ERC20Burnable.  I am currently writing unit tests and am having trouble burning tokens using the burnFrom method, but keep getting an allowance error.
Here are my class definitions -
For MyToken.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import {ERC20Burnable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import {AccessControl} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10 * 10 ** decimals());
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }


    function decimals() public pure override returns (uint8) {
        return 8;
    }
}

and TokenSale.sol:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {MyToken} from "./MyToken.sol";
import {MyNFT} from "./MyNFT.sol";

contract TokenSale {

    uint256 public ratio;
    uint256 public price;
    MyToken public paymentToken; // location of token contract
    MyNFT public nftCollection; // location of nft contract

    constructor(uint256 _ratio, uint256 _price, MyToken _paymentToken, MyNFT _nftCollection) {
        ratio = _ratio;
        price = _price;
        paymentToken = _paymentToken;
        nftCollection = _nftCollection;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 allowance) external {

        paymentToken.approve(spender, allowance);
    }
    
    function buyTokens() external payable {
        
        paymentToken.mint(msg.sender, msg.value * ratio);
    }

    function returnTokens(uint256 amount) external {
        
        paymentToken.burnFrom(msg.sender, amount); 
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount / ratio);    
    }

I am writing a unit test to burn tokens using the following code, but i keep getting an allowance error.  I am approving acc1 and I've approved myTokenContract to burnTokens on behalf of tokenSaleContract, but it won't let me run the returnTokens method.  What am I doing wrong here?
The test code in question:
const TEST_RATIO = 6n;
const TEST_PRICE = 5n;
const TEST_BUY_AMOUNT = "10"; // use parseEther to pass as ether
const TEST_SELL_AMOUNT = "3";
const TEST_TOKEN_ID = 20;
const INTMAX = 2^256-1;

async function fixture() {
  const publicClient = await viem.getPublicClient();
  const [deployer, acc1, acc2] = await viem.getWalletClients();
  const myTokenContract = await viem.deployContract("MyToken", [])
  const tokenSaleContract = await viem.deployContract("TokenSale", [TEST_RATIO, TEST_PRICE, myTokenContract.address, myTokenContract.address,]);
  const MINTER_ROLE = await myTokenContract.read.MINTER_ROLE();
  const giveRoleTx = await myTokenContract.write.grantRole([MINTER_ROLE, tokenSaleContract.address]);
  return { tokenSaleContract, myTokenContract, publicClient, deployer, acc1, acc2 };
}


describe("When a user burns an ERC20 at the Shop contract", async () => {

// Test 7
    it("gives the correct amount of ETH", async () => {
      // initialization
      const { tokenSaleContract, myTokenContract, publicClient, deployer, acc1 } = await loadFixture(fixture);
      const ethBalAcc1Init = await publicClient.getBalance({address: acc1.account.address,});
      
      // acc1 buys tokens, and decrements eth
      const txBuy = await tokenSaleContract.write.buyTokens({ value: parseEther(TEST_BUY_AMOUNT), account: acc1.account});
      const ethBalAcc1Buy = await publicClient.getBalance({address: acc1.account.address},);
      console.log('ethBalBuy is', formatEther(ethBalAcc1Buy));
      const ethBalConBuy = await publicClient.getBalance({address: tokenSaleContract.address},);
      console.log("tokCon: ",myTokenContract.address, "tokSale: ",tokenSaleContract.address, "acc1: ", acc1.account.address, "dep: ", deployer.account.address);

      // acc1 burns tokens and receives eth
      const txAppr = await tokenSaleContract.write.approve([acc1.account.address, parseEther(TEST_BUY_AMOUNT)],{account: acc1.account});
      const tt = await myTokenContract.read.allowance([tokenSaleContract.address, myTokenContract.address]);
      console.log("Allowance for spender myTokenContract for owner tokenSaleContract is:", formatEther(tt));
      
      console.log(formatEther(parseEther(TEST_SELL_AMOUNT)));
      const txSell = await tokenSaleContract.write.returnTokens([parseEther(TEST_SELL_AMOUNT)],{account: acc1.account});


